# The action login is not defined in UsersController

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm attempting to create and implement my own authentication and it keeps trying to reach `Users.login`.

Since I specify which authenticate class to use, implement my own `authenticate()` method, why does it keep attempting to load it?

Full error:

```
Missing Method in UsersController
Cake\Controller\Exception\MissingActionException
Documentation API
The action login is not defined in UsersController
Error: Create UsersController::login() in file: src\Controller\UsersController.php.
```

AppController

```
public function initialize()
{
    ...
    $this->loadComponent('Auth');
    $this->Auth->config('authenticate', ['Sso']);
    ...
}
```

src/Auth/SsoAuthenticate.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Cake\Http\Response;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Log\Log;

class SsoAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    public function authenticate(ServerRequest $request, Response $response)
    {
        Log::debug('SSO Authenticate()');
        //hard coded for testing
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

I had been initially following the lead of the following post: [CakePHP 3 Ldap authentication issue and clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597542/cakephp-3-ldap-authentication-issue-and-clarification)

**Edit #1**

Swapped to returning a valid user and I'm still getting the same results. With every change, I'm using a private window to ensure no session exists, etc.

```
public function authenticate(ServerRequest $request, Response $response)
{
    Log::debug('SSO Authenticate()');
    debug('SSO Authenticate()');

    $table = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $u = $table->get(1);
    debug($u);
    return $u;
}
```

**Edit #2**

Having debug statements, error throwing or even exit will not stop this from going through. This must be a configuration issue? Caching?

```
public function authenticate(ServerRequest $request, Response $response)
{
    Log::debug('SSO Authenticate()');
    debug('SSO Authenticate()');
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Article not found'));
    exit;
}
```

Output of `debug($this->Auth)`

```
object(Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent) {

    'components' => [
        (int) 0 => 'RequestHandler',
        (int) 1 => 'Flash'
    ],
    'implementedEvents' => [
        'Controller.initialize' => 'authCheck',
        'Controller.startup' => 'startup'
    ],
    '_config' => [
        'authenticate' => [
            (int) 0 => 'Sso'
        ],
        'authorize' => null,
        'ajaxLogin' => null,
        'flash' => null,
        'loginAction' => null,
        'loginRedirect' => null,
        'logoutRedirect' => null,
        'authError' => null,
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => true,
        'storage' => 'Session',
        'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.startup'
    ]

}
```

**Edit #3**

Seems this goes through at the moment, even though I'm throwing an error and existing in `authenticate`.

```
<?php
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Cake\Http\Response;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Log\Log;

class SsoAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{

    public function authenticate(ServerRequest $request, Response $response)
    {
        Log::debug('SSO Authenticate()');
        debug('SSO Authenticate()');
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Article not found'));
        exit;
    }
    

    public function getUser(ServerRequest $request)
    {
        $table = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        return $table->get(1)->toArray();
    }
}
?>
```

**Edit #4**

Started from a blank app, implemented the following. Would it be acceptable to throw an error like that if my SSO headers aren't present?

src/Controller/AppController.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth');
    $this->Auth->config('authenticate', ['Sso']);
}
```

src/Auth/SsoAuthenticate.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BaseAuthenticate;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;
use Cake\Http\Response;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use Cake\Core\Exception\Exception;

class SsoAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{
    public function getUser(ServerRequest $request)
    {
        //return true;      //looks for Users.login
        //return false;     //looks for Users.login
        //return ['name' => 'Dan'];   //works!
        $noHeaders = false; //will add appropriate logic here

        if($noHeaders)  //hard stop!
            throw new Exception("No headers configured!");
        else    //insert or update user based on headers and what's in the current db
            return ['name' => "Myself"];    //
    }

    public function authenticate(ServerRequest $request, Response $response){}
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, your authenticator returns `false`, so all requests will be unauthenticated, and the default behavior for unauthenticated requests will kick in, which is to redirect to `Users` controller `login` action.

Comment: @ndm added edit #1, featuring a method that returns a user. I'm still getting the same problem. No output of debug statements either. Also, if something wrong goes into authenticate, what's the best way to halt? Throw an error?

Comment: Is your authenticator being hit at all, eg do you get any debug logs? Returning `false` is the proper way to indicate that the authenticator could not authenticate the current request.

Comment: @ndm I don't think so. No debug output, the throw doesn't happen, nor does the exit. This must be a configuration issue? Caching? See edit #2

Comment: If I change the filename, CakePHP will complain, however. Strange.

Comment: If I remove the method `implementedEvents()`, add the method `getUser()`, it seems to go through (even though I'm throwing an error and using `exit` in `authenticate()`?!

Comment: If `getUser` returns false, it continues to `Users.login`...

Comment: There was never a reference to `implementedEvents()` in the code you've posted, please make sure that you post the complete code! `getUser()` is invoked _before_ `authenticate()`, and it's primarily used by stateless authenticators, and will cause `authenticate()` to not be invoked if it returns a user!

Comment: @ndm my bad. I had assumed it had no bearing. See edit #4, I think I found something that would work? Essentially, no headers = throw error. Insert or update the user based on the headers for the rest.

Comment: Also, where/how would I call setUser($user) in order to manually log the person in?

Comment: Generally you should only throw an exception there in case of an application breaking problem, missing credentials is no such case. If `getUser()` cannot obtain a user, then the method should return `false`. I'm not sure why you're bringing up manually authenticating users, that seems unrelated from the information in the question, but generally that would be done in a controller.

Comment: Once I return the user, from my SsoAuthenticate, I need to authenticate it and $this->Auth->setUser() isn't working in my class, I get an error.

Comment: No, authorization is meant to manage what an authenticated user is allowed to do! If a user needs to be created, then that should happen in the authentication stage, so when the auth component leaves that stage the user exists and is authenticated. I would suggest that you check how other's are doing it, for example https://github.com/UseMuffin/OAuth2